# Changing the website URL with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

It's an easy question but I'm having problems with it. I want to change the website url if a radio button is checked. Here are my bootstrap radio buttons.

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-dark active">
        <input type="radio" name="ai" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Account Information
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-dark">
        <input type="radio" name="ps" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Password And Security
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-dark">
        <input type="radio" name="c" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Contact
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean redirect the user upon radio item click?

Comment: Please provide us with more information. Do you want to change page or just change the URL or load a page using Ajax? What is expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this

```html
<script>
function change_loc(url){
  document.location.href = url;
}
</script>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-dark active">
        <input type="radio" name="ai" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Account Information
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-dark">
        <input type="radio" name="ps" id="option2" autocomplete="off" onclick="change_loc('https://www.google.com/')"> Password And Security
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-dark">
        <input type="radio" name="c" id="option3" autocomplete="off" onclick="change_loc('https://www.amazon.com/')"> Contact
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do with the URL also why have different names on the radio, then they are better off as checkboxes

This will MODIFY the existing URL, which you can change with location or with the history API

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn-group-toggle input[type=radio]").on("click",function() {
    let url = new URL(location.href);
    url.searchParams.set(this.id,this.name)
    console.log(url); // location = url;  
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-dark active">
        <input type="radio" name="ai" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Account Information
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-dark">
        <input type="radio" name="ps" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Password And Security
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-dark">
        <input type="radio" name="c" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Contact
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe JavaScript is needed for this solution. Also the name="" needs to be the same to make them the same group. You may select to have a value="" added.

```
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <input type="radio" name="options" value="ai" id="option1" autocomplete="off" 
    onclick="location.href='www.google.com/ai'" checked> Account Information<br />
        <input type="radio" name="options" value="ps" id="option2" autocomplete="off" 
    onclick="location.href='www.google.com/ps'"> Password And Security<br />
        <input type="radio" name="options" value="c" id="option3" autocomplete="off" 
    onclick="location.href='www.google.com/c'"> Contact<br />
</div>
```